# pandas apply a dictionary mapping to each value in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the following

```
    index                   day          items  size
0     0.0                     1         [8, 9]     2
1     1.0                     2            [1]     1
2     2.0                     3            [4]     1
3     3.0                     4            [3]     1
4     4.0                     5            [4]     1
5     5.0                     6            [4]     1
6     6.0                     7            [4]     1
7     7.0                     8            [4]     1
8     8.0                     9         [3, 8]     2
9     9.0                    10         [3, 8]     2
10   10.0                    11         [3, 5]     2
```

using a mapping:

```
mapping_dict = { 1: "First", 2: "Second", 3: "Third" # and so on }
```

so that *each value* in the lists in `items` get their replacement value:

```
    index                   day         items                 size
0     0.0                     1         ["Eighth", "Ninth"]     2
1     1.0                     2         ["First"]               1
```

Similar to above. I tried using `apply` with a lambda, but each lambda will return the entire list in the row.

Comment: whats happens if no match?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, which will be the fastest method:

```
df['items'] = [[mapping_dict.get(e, e) for e in l] for l in df['items']]
```

or, less efficiently:

```
(df.explode('items')
   .assign(items=lambda d: d['items'].map(mapping_dict))
   .groupby(level=0).agg({'items': list, 'index': 'first', 'day': 'first', 'size': 'first'})
)
```

output:

```
    index  day            items  size
0     0.0    1  [Eighth, Ninth]     2
1     1.0    2          [First]     1
2     2.0    3         [Fourth]     1
3     3.0    4          [Third]     1
4     4.0    5         [Fourth]     1
5     5.0    6         [Fourth]     1
6     6.0    7         [Fourth]     1
7     7.0    8         [Fourth]     1
8     8.0    9  [Third, Eighth]     2
9     9.0   10  [Third, Eighth]     2
10   10.0   11   [Third, Fifth]     2
```

Comment: Maybe in some old pandas solutions you are right, in last not `df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
        
    
    In [248]: %timeit df['items'] = [[mapping_dict.get(e, e) for e in l] for l in df['items']]
    31.3 ms ± 2.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
    
    In [249]: %timeit df['items'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict.get(y, y) for y in x])
    19.6 ms ± 284 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: `apply` is faster like `list comprehesion` here

Comment: @jezrael I don't reproduce those timings, using the latest pandas. Where have you seen that apply got improved?

Comment: some year ago when testing. It is still slow if `axis=1` in `apply`, but in `Series` it is really fast

Comment: what are your timings?

Comment: It's strange that `apply` would be faster. After all this is only doing a loop in both cases. I should dig in the `apply` code

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda function in list comprehension:

```
#if no match return same value
df['items'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict.get(y, y) for y in x])

#if no match return None
df['items'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict.get(y) for y in x])

#if no match remove
df['items'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict[y] for y in x if y in mapping_dict])
```

**Sample**:

```
mapping_dict = { 1: "First", 2: "Second", 3: "Third"}
             
df['items1']= df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict.get(y, y) for y in x])
df['items2']= df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict.get(y) for y in x])
df['items3']= df['items'].apply(lambda x: [mapping_dict[y] for y in x if y in mapping_dict])
print (df)
   index  day   items  size       items1          items2    items3
0    0.0    1  [8, 2]     2  [8, Second]  [None, Second]  [Second]
1    1.0    2     [1]     1      [First]         [First]   [First]
2    2.0    3     [4]     1          [4]          [None]        []
```